# allow soap and wsdl url in .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, soap, wsdl

i have allowed only soap and wsdl url in .htaccess file.
  but while calling soap, it could not load wsdl.

can anyone tell me how to make soap working with this configuration?

please help!

.htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !under_maintenance\.html   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !under_maintenance\.php   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|ico)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api/soap [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api/wsdl [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api_index/http [NC]
RewriteRule .*    http://test.com/under_maintenance.html    [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule .* http://test.com/under_maintenance.php?param=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Provide your .htaccess file here.

Comment: please check .htaccess file